# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Clickable Parent URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a Bootstrap 5 Navabar with the dropdown to show on hover and the parent to be clickable on screens over 992px.

I have got the show on hover to work fine with the following JavaScript.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
if (window.innerWidth > 992) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .nav-item').forEach(function(everyitem){
        everyitem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
            let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
            if(el_link != null){
                let nextEl = el_link.nextElementSibling;
                el_link.classList.add('show');
                nextEl.classList.add('show');
            }
        });
        everyitem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
            let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
            if(el_link != null){
                let nextEl = el_link.nextElementSibling;
                el_link.classList.remove('show');
                nextEl.classList.remove('show');
            }

        })
    });     
}
});
```

And it works great. I am having problems with getting the parent to follow the URL.

Using

```
$('.navbar .nav-item > a').click(function() {  location.href = this.href; } });
```

Does not work and I have been unable to find a suitable solution online.

I have tried

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      location.href = this.href;
    });
})
```

This does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit. Apologies here is the HTML

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="nav-fill w-100 fw-bold text-md-start navbar-nav">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item nav-item-1078">
    <a href="https://website.com/Parent/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Parent
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu depth_0">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-1079">
            <a href="https://website.com/sub-1/" class="dropdown-item ">
                Sub 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-1080">
            <a href="https://website.com/sub-2/" class="dropdown-item ">
                Sub 2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item nav-item-1081">
            <a href="https://website.com/sub-3/" class="dropdown-item ">
                Sub 3
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for this? Please get into the habit of presenting a proper [mre], when you ask a question like this.

Comment: You should be checking window size _inside_ your event listener. What if the window is resized or the orientation changed?

Comment: Do you mean that the code should be

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out how to do what I want using the code below.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
if (window.innerWidth > 992) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .nav-item').forEach(function(everyitem){
        everyitem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
            let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
            if(el_link != null){
                let nextEl = el_link.nextElementSibling;
                el_link.classList.add('show');
                nextEl.classList.add('show');
            }
        });
        everyitem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
            let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
            if(el_link != null){
                let nextEl = el_link.nextElementSibling;
                el_link.classList.remove('show');
                nextEl.classList.remove('show');
            }

        });
        everyitem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
            if(el_link != null){
                location.href = el_link.href;
            }

        });
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple CSS trick to reduce JavaScript code and achieve same result

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle:active {
    /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .nav-item').forEach(function(everyitem){ 
        everyitem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            let el_link = this.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle]');
            if(el_link != null){
                location.href = el_link.href;
            }

        });
    });
```